# how to enter another segue when it only meets some requirements in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

For example, I `control-drag` a login button on my first view controller to the second view controller. Now I want have this result:
When I click `login`, if it meets some requirements(for example, if `1+1 != 2`, it will enter the second view controller). Otherwise it will stay on the first view controller.
This is part of my code:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier
    {
    case .Some("LoginSegue"):

        // if it satifies some requirement, it will enter anther segue, otherwise it says on the original one
       if (1+1)==2
       {

       }
       else
       {

            let loginViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! RegularLogin

            if let temp_username = usernameText!.text
            {
                loginViewController.username = temp_username
                if let temp_password = passwordText!.text
                {
                    loginViewController.password = temp_password



                }

            }
        }
```

[image]

However, even though it doesn't meet the requirement, when I click `login`, it still enter the second view controller. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `prepareForSegue` is the wrong method; it's too late. To prevent this segue from triggering, implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. This is your chance to examine the segue and the situation and return `true` or `false` to permit or deny the segue to go forward.